# remove Attribute "contenteditable" from entire document

Tags: javascript, html

I have the problem that some `<span>` elements have the Attribute "contenteditable=true".

That is a problem it should be false.

I am using this as temporary fix

```
for (i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName("span").length; i++) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("span")[i].removeAttribute("contenteditable");
}
```

But this is not that fast. Is there a better way to remove all "contenteditable" Attributes from the html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to refer span which have `contenteditable` attribute.

```
document.querySelectorAll("span[contenteditable]").forEach(function(el){
  el.removeAttribute("contenteditable");
})
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`, which does not have `forEach` in Firefox for example.

Comment: @dsuckau You'd better check the docs. The node list returned by `querySeletorAll` has a function `forEach`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm using ESR channel of Firefox, depending on my company's guidelines. In latest 50+ Firefox it is implemented! So you should be stil careful or use a polyfill. Many companies/clients use ESR versions, due to extended support.